# Atk4 UI: callback/modal on table cell click

Tags: atk4

What is the best way to attach:

a) PHP callback
b) Open a modal

to a table created like this:

```
$table = $app->add(['Table', 'celled' => true]);
$table->setModel($mod, false);
$table->addColumn('name');
```

?

I tried some examples from doc, but they were not for the Table component, but for Grid and the usage seems to be very different.

Answer (score 2):

I think you better use Grid class. It will have more options and extensions than Table. Table is meant for simple reporting purposes or things like that. For interactive tables - use Grid or CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

Grid is a View which contains table, menu and paginator. To set callback on any view use:

```
$table->on('.class-or-selector', function(..) { });
```

You may also pass arguments:

```
$table->on('.class-or-selector', function($j, $arg1, $arg2) {}, [
    new jsExpression('..'), // passed along as $arg1
    new jsExpression('..'), // passed as $arg2
]);
```

As example, you can use Table's jsRow() function to reference clicked row and fetch "ID":

```
$jsexpr1 = $table->jsRow()->data('id');
```